# Push data from one column to another in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to move values from my OrderNumber column which has a datatype of varchar to my new column in the same table called NewNumber which has a datatype of bigint. So I have many values and here is a couple from the OrderNumber column:

```
-ON12747583
-1749475944
```

I want to be able to put these many values in my NewNumber column that is a bigint and trim off the leading 'ON'. So I should see:

```
NewNumber:  12747583,1749475944
OrderNumber: ON12747583,1749475944
```

Note: the comma is just to separate the values from one another, they are not in the same row.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `REPLACE()` function as

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Old VARCHAR(45),
  New BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO T(Old) VALUES
('ON12747583'),
('1749475944');

UPDATE T
SET New = REPLACE(Old, 'ON', '')
FROM T;
```

---

UPDATE:

I suppose you're storing a some data which doesn't fit **[`BIGINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** since you insist that there is no other characters except `'ON'`. So I suggest that you change the datatype as

```
ALTER TABLE T
ALTER COLUMN New DECIMAL(38, 0);
```

And then run the query

```
UPDATE T
SET New = REPLACE(Old, 'ON', '')
FROM T;
--WHERE if needed
```

Comment: No need for the `CASE`, you can just use `REPLACE`

Comment: @scsimon Yup, sometimes I messed up. :)

Comment: @Sami I got an error converting datatype varchar to bigint when using your statement. can you provide another example please?

Comment: @an1234 Do you have other chars except `'ON'`?

Comment: @Sami no all of them begin with ON the rest are regular numeric values

Comment: What's the results of `SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE TRY_CAST(REPLACE(Old, 'ON', '') AS BIGINT) IS NULL`?

Comment: @an1234 That's unlikely, unless your have a value that's > 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: @Sami it says 'Try_cast' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: Then you aren't on SQL Server 2012 which you have tagged @an1234

Comment: @scsimon I apologize only some of my servers are 2012 and this one is not on 2012 and it has to stay on where it is. server looks like 2009

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a 2009 version @an1234. `select @@version`

Comment: @scsimon My sql management studio is 2016 the server is showing 10.50.6220.0

Comment: @scsimon I just ran a query and came up with this Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 (X64)

Comment: @an1234 It's SQL Server 2008 R2, which is out of support and you should upgrade

Comment: @sami it is company issued or I would. Do you know a fix for my question on my current sql server?

Comment: @an1234 Until you tell use what's the results of `SELECT Old
FROM T
WHERE REPLACE(Old, 'ON', '') LIKE '%[^0-9.]%';`, as it is I can't tell because I don't know how your data looks like

Comment: @Sami There is absolutely no other non numeric characters other than ON

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `STUFF()` for this purpose:

```
UPDATE T
    SET NewNumber = STUFF(OrderNumber, 1, 2, '')
    WHERE OrderNumber LIKE 'ON%';
```

You want to use `STUFF()` so the replacement is specific to the first `'ON'`.  In this case, you may know that the rest of the values of numbers, but I think it is a good habit to use `STUFF()` instead of `REPLACE()`.

Second, you want to limit the rows being updated with a `WHERE` clause.  SQL Server incurs the overhead for updating a row even when no values change.  You want to avoid that overhead if you can.